# Datepicker is not popping up with ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Datepicker is not popping up. I am trying to follow the example **Date picker in a popup** here https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples but when the button is pressed, no popup shows up.

header.component.html

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent，
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule, 
    NgbModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

The calendar is popping up but somehow it is not being displayed. I tried changing the `opacity` and `z-index` values but no success.

[image]

Comment: check if the bootstrap css is actually loaded, also are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no error in the console

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't added the bootstrap css file in `angular.json`

**angular.json**

```
"styles": [
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
],
```

Comment: I have `"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",` as a dependency and I'm importing into my styles file with 


`@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

Comment: I have updated the question with a picture showing the problem, maybe that gives you more information

Comment: create a stackblitz reproduction